# show NativeScript preview to remote persons

Tags: nativescript, preview

I have to show the prototype application made with SideKick to other people in other places. Can I do that? How? I tried distributing the qrCode, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If it's your local app, you may not able to do that. If you are willing to share the code, you may upload the project to Playground and share the link. If you prefer not to share the code, you will have to build the app and send the APK or IPA they can install on their phone.

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much!